# Error en DatetimePicker

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datetime

Buen día,

desarrolle una aplicacion es C# para escritorio, el cual utiliza dos timepickers pero al momento de abrir la aplicacion ya instalada en una pc me lanza el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera saber si alguien pudiera ayudarme como resolver ese problema, al correrlo dentro de Visual Studio corre a la perfección pero en la pc marca ese error siempre que abro una ventana que contenga algún datetimepicker.

Saludos

Comment: Inicializá el `DateTimePicker` en alguna fecha que este dentro de `MinDate` y `MaxDate`

Comment: Por defecto el DateTimePicker toma la fecha y hora actual de la PC en donde se está ejecutando, es probable que tu problema radique ahí.